Recovery of bandlimited function by its integral
We denote Fourier transform as:
$$\hat{f}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-2\pi ikt}f(t)\mathrm{d}t$$
$\textbf{Question:}$
Now we have a bandlimited fucntion $f(t)$, and $\text{supp}(\hat{f})\subset[-\pi, \pi]$. Now define the integral sequence as,
$$\tilde{f}(n) = \int_{n-0.5}^{n+0.5}f(t)\mathrm{d}t, \quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Show that we can recover $f$ from the sequence $\tilde{f}$.
$\textbf{Attempt:}$
Let $F(x) = \int_{x-0.5}^{x+0.5}f(t)\mathrm{d}t$, then $F(n) = \tilde{f}(n)$, then we should have
$$
\hat{F}(k) = \text{sinc}(k) \hat{f}(k)
$$
By shannon sampling theorem, to recover $F(x)$ from $F(n)$, it should hold that $\hat{F}(k)$ is supported on $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$, but we only have it is supported on$[-\pi,\pi]$.

$\tilde f(n)$ seems a convolution product

Define the (bandlimited) function $u$, whose Fourier transform is $\widehat u(k)=\frac 1 {\text{sinc}(k)}$ for $|k|<\frac 1 2$, and $0$ elsewhere. Then you can prove that $f$ can be recovered by $f(t)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \tilde f(n)(u\ast \text{sinc})(t-n)$.

Bonus: The recovery formula above can be proven with no calculus at all, via Shannon's sampling theorem and the action of the Fourier transform on convolutions. Of course, you can also prove it by calculus, it's fun too. But it's equivalent to reproving the Shannon theorem.

Hi @StefanLafon , would you mind giving a further explanation?

They closed the question, preventing an interesting discussion... Anyway: $\tilde f=\chi \ast f$ where $\chi$ is the indicator function of $(-\frac 12, \frac 12)$. Since $f$ is bandlimited, so is $\tilde f$ (easy to check). Thus by Shannon's theorem, $\tilde f$ can be recovered from its samples at integers. Now, since $\widehat \chi = $sinc, it follows that $\widehat u \widehat \chi=\chi$. Thus $\widehat u \widehat {\tilde f}=\widehat u \widehat \chi \widehat f=\chi \widehat f=\hat f$, which implies that $u\ast \tilde f =  f$. Plug this into Shannon's formula for $\tilde f$ for the result.

Final note: The result can be generalized to $\tilde f (n)=\int_{n-\frac 12}^{n+\frac 12} g(n-t)f(t)dt$ where $\widehat g(k)\neq 0$ for $|k|<\frac 12$. You can deconvolve with the function $u$ such that $\widehat u(k)=\frac 1 {\widehat g(k)}$ for $|k|<\frac 12$, and $0$ elsewhere (same formula and same proof as in my previous comments.

@StefanLafon Thanks a lot! So we actually need $\hat{f}(k)=0$ when $|k| \geq \frac{1}{2}$ to ensure $\chi \hat{f} =\hat{f}$?

Yes, it's equivalent, since $\chi(k)=0$ for $|k|>\frac 12$.

So the question was reopened. Let me copy my answer from the comments.
Let $\chi$ be the indicator function of $(-\frac 12, \frac 12)$ (equal to $1$ on this interval, and $0$ elsewhere). Define also the (bandlimited) function $u$, whose Fourier transform is $\widehat u(k)=\frac 1 {\text{sinc}(k)}$ for $|k|<\frac 12$ and $0$ elsewhere. In other words, almost everywhere
$$\widehat u = \frac{\chi}{\text{sinc}}\tag{1}$$
where $\text{sinc}(t)=\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$.
See at the end of this answer for a generalization.
Result: You can recover $f$ from the samples $\{\tilde f(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ via the formula: $$f(t)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \tilde f(n)(u\ast \text{sinc})(t-n)$$
Proof (using Shannon's theorem, very little calculus):
You can verify that the function $\tilde f$ is given by $\tilde f = \chi \ast f$, or, in the Fourier domain $$\widehat {\tilde f} = \widehat \chi \widehat f=\text{sinc}\cdot \widehat f\tag{2}$$
where we have used the fact that $\widehat \chi = \text{sinc}$.
Since $f$ is bandlimited with bandwidth $\frac 12$, so is $\tilde f$ (easy to check). Thus by Shannon's theorem, $\tilde f$ can be recovered from its samples at integers, via the formula: $$\tilde f(t) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \tilde f(n)\,\text{sinc}(t-n)\tag{3}$$
Now, using $(1)$ and $(2)$, it follows that $$\widehat u \widehat {\tilde f} = \chi \widehat f = \widehat f$$
In the time domain, we thus have the deconvolution:
$$u \ast \tilde f = f$$
Plug this into Shannon's formula $(3)$ to get the result.
Generalization: If you define $$\tilde f(n) = \int_{\mathbb R} v(n-t)f(f)dt$$ for any $v$ such that $\widehat v(k) \neq 0$ for almost all $k\in (-\frac 12, \frac 12)$, then you can recover $f$ from $\{\tilde f(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ via
$$f(t)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \tilde f(n) (u \ast \text{sinc})(t-n)$$
where $u$ is defined in the Fourier domain as $\widehat u(k) = \frac {1}{\widehat v(k)}$ for $|k|<\frac 12$ and $0$ elsewhere.
The proof is essentially the same as above. What this result above says is that bandlimited functions are extremely structured signals. Averaging them via convolution with reasonable filters (see note below) doesn't lead to information loss.
Note: From a numerical point of view, the recovery may be more or less stable. It depends on the condition number $$\frac{\max_{|k| < \frac 12} |\widehat u(k)|}{\min_{|k| < \frac 12} |\widehat u(k)|}$$
